# DNS management for WHMCS / cPanel?

Tags: domain-name-system

I currently have WHMCS (www.whmcs.com) that I use for the billing system for my hosting company. It integrates with cPanel and WHM. I want to be able to allow clients to:

1. Change MX Records
2. Change DNS info (CNAME, A Record etc)

1 can be done in cPanel. But 2 not. So my questions are:

1. Is there a program/application available that will give clients access to this? I.e. So they can change their DNS info?
2. How do other companies do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a WHMCS addon to do this.

[cPanel DNS manager for WHMCS](http://www.whmcs.com/appstore/426/DNS-Manager.html)

Answer (score 0):

CPanel offers an API which can be used to provide customers with the DNS Editing abilities, you either need to create your own backend to allow this, or use a client management system which supports it. CPanel also provide a 'CPanel DNS Only' suite to create redundant nameservers, unfortunately at this time it appears WHMCS does not support this.

If this is something you absolutely need, you will need to consider outsourcing the script request or consider changing your CMS to something such as Hostbill (hostbillapp.com).

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ConfigureCluster
http://www.cpanel.net/products/cpanelwhm/related-server-software.html